# WPF Textblock text arrangement

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a label and textbox which are horizontally aligned next to each other.

```
 <TextBlock Width="400" Margin="10" Padding="10">
    <Label Foreground="Yellow" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold" >Heading:</Label>
    <TextBlock  FontSize="13" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Bold" >here is the main contetn and how about adding it to left on seco
        here is the main content and how about adding it to left on seco
    </TextBlock>
</TextBlock>
```

Can i arrange the text of the text block just below the label 
A sample image is attached[image]

Comment: Why the outer element is a `TextBlock`? not a horizontally oriented `StackPanel`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant you want the heading and the text to start on the same line and overflow under the heading. You can do this by using Run elements to display text in the TextBlock you have defined.

```
<TextBlock Width="400" Margin="10" Padding="10" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
    <Run Foreground="Yellow" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold" >Heading:</Run>
    <Run  FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold" >here is the main contetn and how about adding it to left on seco
        here is the main content and how about adding it to left on seco
    </Run>
</TextBlock>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You Use Stack Panel for header And Grid with there properties Horizontal and vertical Alignments,